Other radios can hear my Baofeng but I can't hear them with my Baofeng
this may be a dumb question but I am new to this stuff so don't judge me please,
I just bought Baofeng UV-5R and I tested it with Topcom Twintalker 1302, which is PMR radio. I set my frequency on my Baofeng to 446.00625 and tried it. I could clearly hear my voice from the Topcom, but when I tried transmitting from the Topcom I couldn't hear me talking. Note that the Baofeng was registering a signal. I just couldn't hear my voice. When I blowed inside the microphone I could hear some noise from the Baofeng.
I tried scanning for both CTCSS and DCS but I couldn't find any specific configuration that would work. And I even found another radio that is just PMR and tried with it but got similar results, the only difference is that I had to setup CTCSS in order to hear myself from it. But still I couldn't hear myself when I transmitted from the another radio.
In other words, these radios can hear the Baofeng under certain conditions, but not the other way around.
My SQL is set to 3 and I tried even with 2. Band VHF, TXP low and SAVE to off.

Have you tried the NFM setting on your Baofeng? I believe PMR channels are all NFM. Also, you should be aware that there may not a jurisdiction where getting those 2 radios to interoperate is actually legal: Baofeng amateur radios are typically legal only for use on amateur freqs due to its power and antenna capabilities.

Try turning up the volume. Also, turn off CTCSS and DCS because you do not need those and it just makes things more complicated. Turn off the squelch (SQL) completely so you can hear everything. If you can, maybe return the radio and get it from a more reputable seller and not some Chinese knockoff.

Try from further away.  Inexpensive receivers can get overloaded and quit working if the signal is too strong.

I too discovered this issue preparing my hurricane kit. After about 20 minutes of muttered curses, I stumbled over this on the Baofeng menu DTMFST has a value selected.As soon as I set this to off the radios would hear each other. I am thinking this must be a default value from Chirp as I never set this.
